# Update to first cell in Google Sheet color change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The other day I posted about getting a google sheet to change the background color of a cell to red if any cell in that row had a red background. I now am attempting to make it check for yellow, orange, and red and change the first cell accordingly (with each color superseding next, so yellow would be only if no orange or red cells for example).

The code provided by Serge insas that worked perfectly was this:

```
  function MakeRed(){
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
  var first_column = "B";
  var first_row = 1;
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var active_row = 1;
  var range_input = sheet.getRange(1,1,last_row,last_column);
  var range_output = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgroundColors();
  var color = "#ff0000";

  for(var r = 0; r < cell_colors.length; r++) {
    var rowWoColA = cell_colors[r].slice(1);
    if(rowWoColA.indexOf(color)>-1) {
      cell_colors[r][0]=color;
    } else {
      cell_colors[r][0]="#ffffff";
    }
  }
  range_input.setBackgroundColors(cell_colors);// update sheet colors
}
```

I modified the code to what I thought would work for this revision but I am getting nothing (and strangely in Google Sheets the Execution Transcript remains blank?)

```
  function ColorOfCol(){
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
  var first_column = "B";
  var first_row = 1;
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var active_row = 1;
  var range_input = sheet.getRange(1,1,last_row,last_column);
  var range_output = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgroundColors();
  var color1 = "#ffff00";
  var color2 = "#ff9900";
  var color3 = "#ff0000";

  for(var r = 0; r < cell_colors.length; r++) {
    var rowWoColA = cell_colors[r].slice(1);
    if(rowWoColA.indexOf(color1)>-1) {
      cell_colors[r][0]=color1;
    } else if(rowWoColA.indexOf(color2)>-1) {
      cell_colors[r][0]=color2;
    } else if(rowWoColA.indexOf(color3)>-1) {
      cell_colors[r][0]=color3;      
    } else {
      cell_colors[r][0]="#ffffff";
    }
  }
  range_input.setBackgroundColors(cell_colors);// update sheet colors
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me, other than the complaint that `setBackgroundColors()` is deprecated. (Use `setBackgrounds()` instead.) Do you have multiple copies of `ColorOfCol`? Do you have data in the _active_ sheet?

Comment: OK, it is working except the trigger I had set (using onChange event for the sheet) no longer seems to cause the code to run. If I manually run the code in the code editor, or set a new trigger by time (every minute for testing) then this code does just what I want. Trying to figure out why triggers that worked before don't now.

Comment: Check whether you're using any services that require authentication. The onChange trigger runs anonymously, which limits what it can do.

Answer (score 0):

The code added here is working perfectly fine for me. However make sure you are not testing this code on an empty Google Sheet, as the below code returns values based on the text values in the cells not based on the background colors.

```
var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
 var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
```

Also able to view the Execution Transcript in Apps Script console correctly.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my earlier comment, the code works as long as you meet the conditions. Even with no data in the sheet, though, the first call to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` *should* have resulted in an entry in the execution transcript. You're right to think something is weird with that.

It's good practice to validate expected conditions, and alert users to important ones if they aren't met. In your case, if there's no data in the spreadsheet then you'll read no colors - that would be sad. You can check the condition and throw an error, for example:

```
if (cell_colors.length == 0) throw new Error( 'No data in sheet' );
```

Cool thing - using `getDataRange()` avoids this because it always returns a range, even when a sheet is empty, in which case it would be just `A1`. Regardless, the only rows that will be checked will be those with data in them - so you may still see rows that don't have the expected color in column A.

Here's a more compact version of your function:

```
function ColorOfCol(){
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
  var range_input = sheet.getDataRange();
  var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgrounds();
  if (cell_colors.length == 0) throw new Error( 'No data in sheet' );

  // List of colors in priority order, default at end.
  var color = ["#ffff00","#ff9900","#ff0000","#ffffff"];

  for (var r = 0; r < cell_colors.length; r++) {
    // check for all colors EXCEPT our default, the last in color[]
    for (var b=0; b<color.length-1; b++) {
      // -1 means not found, but 0 means found in first column, which we don't care about
      if (cell_colors[r].indexOf(color[b])>0) {
        // found this color, stop searching, with 'b' == found color
        break;
      }
    }
    // 'b' will contain the color index. If none found, it will be the last color, our default.
    cell_colors[r][0]=color[b];
  }
  range_input.setBackgrounds(cell_colors);// update sheet colors
}
```